# (Javascript) How to make a image open double link

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hyperlink

How to create a [code like this](http://www.firefall.cc/). when an image is being clicked and 2 links will open, one in the same window and another as a pop-up windows.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.firefall.cc/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/start-download-crack.gif" class="yourlink">
```

JS:

```
<script>
$('img.yourlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://livemecca.blogspot.com');
    window.location.href = 'http://firefall.cc/';
});
</script>
```

Comment: hello..thanks for your reply, but the html and js you provided is not working.   i have added this in blogger html/javascript and it's showing the code.... and where do i insert the image link ????

Comment: I guess nw it should be fine...

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: no....is this ok ??                                                                                                           <script>
$('img.http://www.firefall.cc/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/start-download-crack.gif').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://www.firefall.cc/');
    window.location.href = 'http://livemecca.blogspot.com/';
});
</script>

Comment: still not solved...the code isn't working

Comment: You didnt made the changes properly, please view the updaed code with the values you want. `yourlink` is just the className of `img`.

Comment: sorry i am very weak at this ...   do i change this     **img.yourlink**     to image link ????

Comment: NP just add ditto `<img .... >` where you want the image and paste the code of the `script` tag where your `JS` is. It will work.

Comment: Just dont forget to mark it as correct answer if it works.

Comment: sorry to disturb you again............  can u please edit the code again and keep the image link same and make this link **http://livemecca.blogspot.com/** open in pop-up window and make this link **http://www.firefall.cc/** open in same window....      your current code's image is non-clickable

Comment: Done.. I hope that you are using jQuery?

Comment: :) just mark it as a correct answer

Comment: sure...but i can't find the option :p

Comment: Their is tick mark near the left top of my answer :-P

Comment: You should mark it for others to find the right solution.